# IntelliJ IDEA: How to display warnings in the project tree?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, warnings

I recently moved from Eclipse to IntelliJ and I was really used to see any kind of warnings in the tree of my project in eclipse.

I think in IntelliJ by default compilation errors are displayed in the project tree or maybe it worked by enabling the "build project automatically" setting. But I did't find any way to enable the same for simple warnings (e.g. unused imports).
Does somebody know how I could achieve this or anything similar to it so I can simple get informed about any warnings?

I would be happy about any help I can get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most inspections run in the background only for the currently open file for the performance reasons, therefore there is no way to mark the files with inspection warnings in the project view.

Use Analyze | Inspect Code to get the list of the files with warnings.